# Save local image from network flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart

the flutter code below takes care of recovering an image from a backend node.js what I have to do is save the image locally, in a specific path but when I run the code below I have the following errors, how can I do to solve this? 
I use cachemanager to save the image locally but one of the errors is precisely on cachemanager what is this due to?

**Error:**

```
'Image' is imported from both       
'package:pdf/widgets.dart' and 'package:image/src/image.dart'.
import 'package:image/image.dart';                                      
^^^^^                                                                   
lib/Model/Supporto.dart:20:31: Error: The getter 'CacheManager' isn't defined for the
class 'SaveFile'.
 - 'SaveFile' is from 'package:MyApp/Model/Supporto.dart' ('lib/Model/Supporto.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or
field named 'CacheManager'.
     var cacheManager = await CacheManager.getInstance()
```

**Dart Code:**

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
    import 'package:MyApp/Controller/Rapporto.dart';
    import 'package:MyApp/Model/Cantiere.dart';
    import 'package:MyApp/Model/Supporto.dart';
    import 'package:MyApp/Model/Utente.dart' show Utente;
    import 'dart:io' as Io;
    import 'package:image/image.dart';

    import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

    //Classe che rapprresenta il rapporto
    class Rapporto {
      //Costruttore
      Rapporto(Utente u, Cantiere c) {
        this.utente = u;
        this.c = c;
      }

       //Funzione: permette di recuperare la testata del rapportino
       static Future<bool> getTestata() async{
         bool ret=false;
         String testata=await RapportoController.getTestata(); //http://localhost:8989/rapportini/immagine/testata
        if( testata!=null){
          if(testata.length>0){
             SaveFile sf=new SaveFile();
             final file = await sf.getImageFromNetwork(testata);
             //Recupero il path locale del dispositivo
             var path = await sf.localPath;
             Image image = decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
             //Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120,120,);

        //Salvataggio immagine
        try{
          new Io.File('assets/temp/testata.jpg').writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(image));
           ret=true;
        }
        catch(ex){
          ret=false;
        }

          }
        } 
        return ret;
      }
    }

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as Io;
import 'package:image/image.dart';

import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

//Classe che si occupa del salvataggio dei file sul filesystem
class SaveFile {

  //Recupero del path locale
  Future<String> get localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }
  //Recupero dell'immagine dalla rete
   Future<Io.File> getImageFromNetwork(String url) async {

     var cacheManager = await CacheManager.getInstance();
     Io.File file = await cacheManager.getFile(url);
     return file;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from your error, you following two file contains same class Image.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
```

1) easiest way to solve is that if you don't require anyone of this files then remove it and you are good to go.

2) If you need both file's in this file then you have to import file using allies, so that you can specify which object you want to create from while file.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as i;
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as p;
```

now, when you want to create object from image library then create following way same as pdf file.

```
 i.classname variablename = i.classname();
```

Answer (score 1):

> 'Image' is imported from both
>   'package:pdf/widgets.dart' and 'package:image/src/image.dart'.
>   import 'package:image/image.dart';

It looks like both of these imported packages has an instance named `Image`, try to use `hide` to ignore the unwanted instance like this:

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' hide Image;
```